# Forward and reply email using DELPHI and INDY 10 components

Tags: delphi, indy, indy10

Does Indy component suite offers any functions or support  or e mail **forewarding**  or **reply** to ...  processing.

I expect the mail body is extended with the sending params. Using other mail programs sometimes the mail text is changed the the > character for each line.

Comment: You can build your own email client with Indy components and you can do whatever you like, but you have to do it in your code. Forwarding or Reply is at least simple sending a mail :o)

Answer (score 4):

You use `TIdPOP3` or `TIdIMAP4` to receive emails, and `TIdSMTP` to send emails.  Replying/Forwarding is just a matter of downloading a `TIdMessage` via POP3/IMAP, updating its Recipients, Subject, etc as needed, and then sending it with SMTP.

Comment: OK : I have to write the code myself. Thanks for the info. Did not want to reinvent the wheel

Comment: @user writing code is what programmers usually do. For other kind of users, there's plenty of email clients, like Outlook, Thunderbird, etc.

Comment: @jachguate - I view my job as trying not to write any code as hard as possible!

Comment: @Leonardo I do it also, after reinventing some wheels to learn how the wheel looks from the inside to build skills and criteria to get things done.